# What does "the bottom had dropped out of his stomach" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> A hundred and fifty points lost. That put Gryffindor in last place. In one night, they'd ruined any chance Gryffindor had had for the house cup. Harry felt as though **the bottom had dropped out of his stomach**. How could they ever make up for this?

I can find these phrases on the web: [bottom drops out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bottom+drops+out), [bottom drops out of the market](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bottom+drops+out+of+the+market), and [bottom drops out of one's world](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bottom+drops+out+of+my+world). But I can't find "**the bottom had dropped out of his stomach**" anywhere. What does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bottom of (one's) stomach" would be another way of saying "the pit of (one's) stomach":

> The lower abdomen regarded as the seat of strong feelings, especially
>   anxiety. - [Oxford Living Dictionaries entry for "pit"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pit)

A "sinking feeling" in the pit of your stomach, for example, can represent [anxiety, or a feeling of loss](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/takeonestep/depression/ask-world_1.html), or fear. The bottom dropping out, then, would be an extreme instance of such feelings, as the pit didn't just sink, it's gone!

Comment: Is it the same as *bottom of one's heart*?

Comment: No, the locations (where some people do actually get some physical sensation) are different. Bottom of your heart is more in the chest region. Also, "bottom of your heart" is often just used for stating the depth of the feeling, without any physical sensations involved.